# Car battery terminal sensor alternative?

Tags: batteries, automotive

I recently tried to replace a car battery, and on it was connected a negative terminal (ground) battery sensor which had a few sensitive corroded bolts that accidentally split. The 2 cables for ground and sensor ground connect perpendicularly on opposing sides of the terminal. The part which connects the sensor cable is insulated with what i'm assuming is some sort of plastic. This part is fairly expensive compared to a typical universal car battery terminal because of this sensor isolation. Here is a picture of it. One connection is on the bottom left with two cables, green and white. Top part is the sensor connection with a metallic plate and hole over the bolt.

[image]

Here is a universal car battery terminal.

[image]

People who have tried messing with this without the isolated ground ended up getting the light inside the dashboard which says there is something faulty with the battery and in some cases, it doesn't get a readout for the voltage level etc. So they took the universal battery terminal and did a somewhat similar thing as in the 1st image and put a large plastic piece over the top and a bigger bolt which connects to the sensor plate and touches the plastic. Is this enough for a normal car operation or should i just the more expensive battery terminal instead? Let me know if there's alternative for this type of connector

Comment: Wrong site - look for an automotive repair site on stack exchange. Also questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic as are questions on commercial electronics goods that aren't backed by schematics or data sheets.

Comment: $50 on Ebay, maybe $25 used in a junk yard.  over 100 cars with similar design

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y3v9v8mg

Comment: It's just a practical question whether a piece of plastic can replace the sensor ground in the universal design long term. Thanks for the link Tony

Comment: Easy enough to find for $69 or so. https://i.imgur.com/jZ991tv.png That's like 30-45 minutes of shop labour.

Comment: Note the 2 grounds are not "isolated"...  They're still gonna be connected to the same piece of metal.  IMO what might be the reason for this is, it avoids the sensitive sensor ground reference from being disturbed by high currents in the other wire.  No wire is a zero-ohm conductor.   So as the current passes, the ground voltage would 'bounce'  (i.e. rise) if the sensor were connected anywhere else.  Whether or not it matters in YOUR application is impossible for anybody here to know.  But it's best to replace with the same part it originally - Presume the design engineers did this on purpose